# Websockets Connect call failed

Tags: python, ubuntu, websocket

Написал простенькие серверную и клиентскую часть на вебсокетах. На локальной пк протестил, все работает. Залил серверную часть на удаленный сервер, запустил. Добавил порт `ufw allow 3636`. Пробую подключаться как клиент с того же сервера(из терминала), все работает. При удаленном подключении выдает ошибку `Connect call failed`. Что может блокировать внешнее подключение? код клиентской части:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import time

async def hello():
    while True:
        async with websockets.connect('ws://test.com:3636') as websocket:
            await websocket.send('test')
            greeting = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"< {greeting}")
            time.sleep(10)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

На сервере поменял строчку `start_server = websockets.serve(test, 'localhost', 8001)` на `start_server = websockets.serve(hello, '', 8001)` Теперь корректно работает.